# Connecting phalcon webapp to an AWS RDS mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, phalcon

I am trying to connect my RDS to my phalcon app. I have settings in my security group that allows access to the database from my server and from localhost. Here is some of my code from my index.php file

```
$config = new Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini("../config/config.ini");
$di->set('db', function() use ($config){
    try {
        $db = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
              "host" => $config->development->host,
              "username" => $config->development->username,
              "password" => $config->development->password,
              "dbname" => $config->development->dbname
          ));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die("<b>Error when initializing database connection:</b> " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $db;
});
```

Then I try a call to my database in one of my controllers here:

```
public function indexAction()
{
  $users = Users::find();
  echo "There are ", count($users), "\n";
}
```

When I run that controller the page times out and throws this error:

```
Error when initializing database connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out
```

The data in the config file is correct. I am able to connect to it just fine via the terminal. What am I doing wrong? Any thoughts/suggestions/insights? Thanks

Comment: Does  AWS DB have the same port number like 3306 ? try to set port to your mysql connection.

Comment: First of, fix `count($users)` to `$users->count()` and `,` to `.`